# Creating submodels, user friendly way

Tags: django, django-models

**Django 1.9.8**

There is a model. And there are submodels.
One to many relationships.

Examples: person and bank accounts.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, blank=False)

class Account(models.Model):
    account = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, blank=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Sometimes it is much more practical to let a user create submodels not one by one, but as if in a list of input fields. S/he presses a plus sign and another input field for a new submodel is added. Then another etc. This way everything is observable, table-like. And one submit button which triggers validation and creation of submodels.

Much more friendly than creating submodels one by one.

I have prepared a prototype: https://whispering-everglades-55047.herokuapp.com/

Ajax used.

This must be a typical pattern. Could you suggest me a ready made application for this purpose. I can't find myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The excellent [django-autocomplete-light](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light) package should be exactly what you're looking for.
It allows the end user to create `owners` in an `AccountFormView`, for example, through the use of a "+" button with 'add another' functionality (outside the admin).

Comment: Well, the application seems huge. Could you point at the very example. This is the examples for all kind of use cases http://dal-yourlabs.rhcloud.com/admin/ What case is mine?

Comment: The examples outside the admin unfortunately aren't complete any longer. Try http://dal-yourlabs.rhcloud.com/admin/linked_data/testmodel/4/change/ for what you can expect outside the admin, too. See the tutorial on https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#creation-of-new-choices-in-the-autocomplete-form for help on creating new items outside the admin.